# How to use Shapefile in Pysal

Tags: shapefile, pysal

I want result of the points intersecting in the given polygon, but I am getting an error.

My code is:

```
from pysal.cg.standalone import get_polygon_point_intersect
poly=pysal.open('Busroute_buffer.shp')
point=pysal.open('pmpml_24.shp')

i=get_polygon_point_intersect(poly,point)
```

But I am getting the error message:

> 'PurePyShpWrapper' object has no attribute 'bounding_box'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pysal.open` returns a shape "file" object, not shapes.

To get the shapes out you need to iterate over the file, or call the file's read method, which returns a list of shapes. This will return a list even if there is only 1 shape in your file. `get_polygon_point_intersect` takes exactly 1 polygon and 1 point, so you'd need to call it for each point/polygon you want to compare.

```py
point_file = pysal.open('points.shp')
polygon_file = pysal.open('polygons.shp')
# .read with no arguments returns a list of all shapes in the file.
polygons = polygon_file.read()
for polygon in polygons:
    # for x in shapefile: iterates over each shape in the file.
    for point in point_file:
        if get_polygon_point_intersect(polygon, point):
            print point, 'intersects with', polygon
```

There are other perhaps more efficient ways of doing this as well. See the [`pysal.cg.locators`](https://pysal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/cg/locators.html) for more information.

*The above code is untested and for example purposes only.